# How to install django cors on server host computer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, heroku, digital-ocean, django-cors-headers

I developed a webapp using Django framework and hosted it on Digital Ocean. The server is supposed to receive a Json from a client written using Ruby rails framework.

The Django app cannot see the Json and so I want use `django-cors-headers` https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers which require me to install `django-cors-headers`,  but I have already hosted the app (i.e. the server).
My questions are ( sorry I am newbie)

1. Is it possible to install `django-cors-headers` using the `pip install django-cors-headers`  on the server host computer at Digital Ocean using may be PUTTY or Winscp? If yes, pls how do i do it?
2. Did I choose the right solution to my problem?

Below is the code for the server (views.py) and I am using Django 1.9 and python 2.7.6

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import JsonResponse
import json
def qucserver (request):
if request.method == 'POST':
   print request.body
   jsdata = json.loads(request.body)
   reply = {"data": jsdata}
   return JsonResponse  ( reply )
else:
    message = 'You submitted an empty form.'
    reply = {"Error": message}
    return JsonResponse (reply)
```

The output is always

```
  {data: "json = JSON_DATA"}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have shell access you certainly ought to be able to install the `django-cors-headers` app or any other app using `pip`. However if your virtualenv is read only, you can simply copy the files from django-cors-headers into your project.

Comment: The django-cors-headers folder consists of one folder called corsheaders and some other files. which of these Iam going to copy or you mean I copy all files and folders

Comment: It is the folder named corsheaders that you need to copy to your project

Comment: Suppose that my django project folder is 'mySite' which consists of  'mySite'   folder ,  myApp folder, and the manager.py file. where will I put the corsheaders folder @e4c5

Comment: then you should end up with a mySite/corsheaders folder which contains the files in https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/tree/master/corsheaders

Comment: There are two mySite folders: The outer one and the inner one. I am I to put inside the outer one OR the inner one. Thank you in advance. @e4c5

Comment: Okay Thank you. I will give a try. @4c5

Comment: I did all what you asked me to do and got  "Internal Server Error". @4c5

Comment: That is a different question. Post it with the full stacktrace.